# Fresh and Empty Tomcat 7.0 install eating a lot of CPU

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

ubuntu, 11.04, 11.10. tomcat 7.0.25-7.0.28, jdk sun 1.6_30 - 1.6_33.

Unpacked, removed webapp folder. After catalina startup top shows
CPU eating by tomcat 170% on 1cpu x64 4 core. on 2cpu x64 4core it
shows up to 400%.

There are no appications installed into tomcat. Tried to figure out
threads which consumes the cpu - below is 5 top threads:

```
"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040a7f000 nid=0x166c waiting on condition

"ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007feaf0666800 nid=0x16ad sleeping[0x00007feafe011000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:148)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000004204f800 nid=0x16ab waiting on condition [0x00007feafead1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:148)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000041d1b800 nid=0x16a9 sleeping[0x00007feafe405000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1517)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040a39000 nid=0x1665 runnable
```

Looks like nothing interresting. So, I'm stucked. Does anybody
know where to go further ? One more thing: have several virtual
boxes with almost identical setup - and never see such huge cpu
consumption.

Comment: Make sure you're not hit by the leap second bug. (you might need to reboot, if you havn't done so since June 30)

Comment: Little test Which runs only Thread.sleep in main consumes up to ~80% cpu. Is there any way to fix it without reboot ? I just cannot reboot the host machine.

Comment: You were right. Fixed. /etc/init.d/ntp stop; date; date `date +"%m%d%H%M%C%y.%S"`; date; found here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/railo/-hz3ckuaCT0. Without reboot.

Answer (score 1):

A thread in status `TIMED_WAITING` doesn't need CPU cycles. As long as all threads are in this state, Tomcat can't be the cause of the load.

What else can you do?

1. Run Tomcat in a profiler. Unlike a thread dump (which just shows you the current state), a profiler will collect profiling information. That will allow you to see which method(s) use how much time.
2. Leave at least one app in the webapp folder. I'm not sure what Tomcat does when it doesn't find **anything** to do.
3. Check whether Tomcat looks into the webapp folder that you think it does. Maybe an environment variable can influence this.
4. This might happen because Tomcat is starting. Unlikely but maybe waiting a couple of minutes might help.
5. How much RAM do you have left? Also unlikely because that should give a huge load but the CPUs would be pretty idle.

Comment: 19061 mike      20   0 4370m  95m 9.8m S  169  0.6   1:00.74 java

Comment: The running tomcat instance consumes 170% cpu. the catalina.out claims that the 'INFO: Server startup in 595 ms'. Doesn't matter is it contains any webapp or not. Theads listed above consumes approx 60%, and ~30% other in order they were listed. This is the primary reason why i writing here. The threads above doing nothing except consumig all the cpu.

Comment: Run it in a profiler. Chances are that Tomcat is processing lots of requests in quick succession but you don't see them because it happens too quickly. Or start Tomcat in a debugger and set breakpoints where `Thread.sleep()`/`Object.wait()` is called. Also check the timeouts given; `Thread.sleep()` with a 1ms timeout will be much like an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with high cpu usage in a java "VM Periodic Task Thread".

The cause of the problem ultimately ended up being due to a linux issue with leap seconds, as detailed in this blog post: [java leap second bug – 30 June / 1 July 2012 – fix](http://blog.wpkg.org/2012/07/01/java-leap-second-bug-30-june-1-july-2012-fix/).

Following the steps listed there (stopping ntpd, resetting the date, restarting ntpd) resolved the issue of high cpu usage for me.